# Good Resource for Classifying Statistical Mechanics Problems

Tags: statistical-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations

I've grown very interested in statistical mechanics ever since I took my first course in it. However, it feels like it is just overflowing with many types of problems and plenty of categories to consider.

For example, a quick search of just phase transitions led to this big list:

```
1-dimensional phase transitions
First-order transitions
Gas-liquid phase transitions
Glass transition
Isotropic-nematic phase transition
Jamming transition
Kosterlitz-Thouless transition
Landau theory of second-order phase transitions
Liquid-liquid phase transitions
Martensitic phase transitions
Nematic-smectic phase transition
Nonequilibrium phase transitions
Order-disorder transitions
Quantum phase transitions
Second-order transitions
Solid-liquid phase transitions
Topological phase transitions
Vapour-liquid phase transitions
```

Considering how phase transitions are just an aspect of stat mech and each of these can be applied (at least I suspect) to countless physical systems I think a depth first approach is pretty useless for someone like me at the moment.

The field is just initially so daunting that it seems hard to explore with a roadmap of the interesting features.

My question is:

Are there a good outline of the more complicated side of statistical mechanics that I can use to basically just get a brief introduction to a comprehensive list of terms I'll need to know to effectively add statistical physics to my list of toolkits for solving problems. Extra kudos if this outline includes many examples of physical systems that utilize each model.

Comment: If "brief but comprehensive" had been an option in the stone age, we would have had interstellar travel some 18,000 years ago. If you want to get a significant level of understanding of any topic you will have to do a significant amount of work.

Comment: I meant brief in depth and comprehensive in breadth.

Comment: At the moment I'm just looking for a primer on the various topics with some light discussion on how they are used to try and decide on what to really dig into next.